# What's wrong of my zabbix with "404 Page Not Found"?

Tags: php, apache, postgresql, http-status-code-404, zabbix

I have install zabbix 2.4 (using rpms) in CentOS 6.8 with psql 8.4.20, apache httpd 2.2.15, php 5.6.22, but my 80 port was occupied by nginx, so I changed the httpd port to 8080, and when I restart the httpd service:

```
[root@kf8 ~]# service httpd restart
stop httpd：                                               [yes]
start httpd：[Mon Aug 22 19:40:03 2016] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
[Mon Aug 22 19:40:03 2016] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName
                                                           [yes]
[root@kf8 ~]#
```

and I have start the zabbix-server/agent, the process listed below:

```
[root@kf8 ~]# ps aux|grep zabbix
zabbix     2616  0.0  0.0 163304  2832 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
zabbix     2623  0.0  0.0 163340  2404 ?        S    16:48   0:00    zabbix_server: configuration syncer [synced configuration in 0.007229 sec, idle 60 sec]
zabbix     2624  0.0  0.0 163304  2016 ?        S    16:48   0:00     zabbix_server: db watchdog [synced alerts config in 0.005168 sec, idle 60 sec]
zabbix     2625  0.0  0.0 261388  3596 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: poller #1 [got 0 values in 0.000070 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2626  0.0  0.0 261388  3596 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: poller #2 [got 0 values in 0.000079 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2628  0.0  0.0 261388  3596 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: poller #3 [got 0 values in 0.000076 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2629  0.0  0.0 261388  3596 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: poller #4 [got 0 values in 0.000075 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2630  0.0  0.0 261388  3596 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: poller #5 [got 0 values in 0.000074 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2631  0.0  0.0 261388  3596 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: unreachable poller #1 [got 0 values in 0.000072 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2632  0.0  0.0 163304  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: trapper #1 [processed data in 0.000000 sec, waiting for connection]
zabbix     2633  0.0  0.0 163304  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: trapper #2 [processed data in 0.000000 sec, waiting for connection]
zabbix     2634  0.0  0.0 163304  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: trapper #3 [processed data in 0.000000 sec, waiting for connection]
postgres   2635  0.0  0.0 217652  5160 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2636  0.0  0.0 163304  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: trapper #4 [processed data in 0.000000 sec, waiting for connection]
zabbix     2637  0.0  0.0 163304  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: trapper #5 [processed data in 0.000000 sec, waiting for connection]
zabbix     2638  0.0  0.0 163752  1824 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: icmp pinger #1 [got 0 values in 0.000103 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2639  0.0  0.0 163304  1988 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: alerter [sent alerts: 0 success, 0 fail in 0.000385 sec, idle 30 sec]
zabbix     2640  0.0  0.0 163616  2136 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: housekeeper [deleted 0 hist/trends, 0 items, 0 events, 0 sessions, 0 alarms, 0 audit items in 0.003631 sec, idle 1 hour(s)]
postgres   2641  0.0  0.0 217652  5160 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2642  0.0  0.0 163304  2092 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: timer #1 [processed 0 triggers, 0 events in 0.000045 sec, 0 maintenances in 0.000000 sec, idle 30 sec]
postgres   2643  0.0  0.0 217652  5156 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2644  0.0  0.0 163304  2008 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: http poller #1 [got 0 values in 0.000521 sec, idle 5 sec]
postgres   2645  0.0  0.0 217652  5156 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2646  0.0  0.0 260936  3548 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: discoverer #1 [processed 0 rules in 0.000418 sec, idle 60 sec]
postgres   2647  0.0  0.0 217652  5148 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2648  0.0  0.0 163308  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: history syncer #1 [synced 0 items in 0.000025 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2649  0.0  0.0 163308  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: history syncer #2 [synced 0 items in 0.000019 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2650  0.0  0.0 163308  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: history syncer #3 [synced 0 items in 0.000025 sec, idle 5 sec]
postgres   2651  0.0  0.0 217744  5908 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2652  0.0  0.0 163308  2004 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: history syncer #4 [synced 0 items in 0.000023 sec, idle 5 sec]
postgres   2653  0.0  0.0 217736  5988 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2654  0.0  0.0 217780  6120 ?        Ss   16:48   0:01 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2655  0.0  0.0 163304  2008 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: escalator [processed 0 escalations in 0.000228 sec, idle 3 sec]
zabbix     2656  0.0  0.0 163304  2020 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_server: proxy poller #1 [exchanged data with 0 proxies in 0.000070 sec, idle 5 sec]
zabbix     2657  0.0  0.0 163304  1780 ?        S    16:48   0:01 zabbix_server: self-monitoring [processed data in 0.000041 sec, idle 1 sec]
postgres   2658  0.0  0.0 217652  5164 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2659  0.0  0.0 217652  5176 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2661  0.0  0.0 217652  5168 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2662  0.0  0.0 217652  5536 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2663  0.0  0.0 217652  5176 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2664  0.0  0.0 217652  5172 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2665  0.0  0.0 217652  5176 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2666  0.0  0.0 217652  5172 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2667  0.0  0.0 217652  5176 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2668  0.0  0.0 217652  5172 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2669  0.0  0.0 217652  5184 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2670  0.0  0.0 217652  5172 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
postgres   2671  0.0  0.0 217740  6068 ?        Ss   16:48   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
zabbix     2746  0.0  0.0  77136  1384 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_agentd -c /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
zabbix     2748  0.0  0.0  77136  1976 ?        S    16:48   0:06 zabbix_agentd: collector [idle 1 sec]          
zabbix     2749  0.0  0.0  77136  1216 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_agentd: listener #1 [waiting for connection]
zabbix     2750  0.0  0.0  77136  1216 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_agentd: listener #2 [waiting for connection]
zabbix     2751  0.0  0.0  77136  1216 ?        S    16:48   0:00 zabbix_agentd: listener #3 [waiting for connection]
postgres   2812  0.0  0.0 218652  7768 ?        Ss   16:49   0:00 postgres: zabbix zabbix [local] idle              
root       4790  0.0  0.0 103328   908 pts/1    S+   19:42   0:00 grep zabbix
```

But I can not connect 2 the website, and I can not find and error in the  zabbix-server/agent's error log files, though I open the most detailed log level.

The website shown like this:

---

404 Page Not Found

### The page you requested was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://yourzabbixserverIP:8080/zabbix to access the zabbix web UI and trace the apache error logs that are stored in /var/log/httpd/error_log.
What does the error log say?

Comment: It needn't to be an answer that solve the issue. If you still need to ask question to be clear about problem, do not place an answer yet.

Comment: I copy all the php files 2 apache's resource folder , than I restart the httpd , the website shown! Thank U!